# proof using Cauchy Schwarz inequality

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, inequality

I have been trying to understand the proof of Lemma2 in the paper: Xie, M., & Yang, Y. (2003). Asymptotics for generalized estimating equations with large cluster sizes. The Annals of Statistics, 31(1), 310-347.

Specifically, I need help with the following step:

> Proof. We only need to verify the LIndeberg condition for the double arrays $Z_{nm,i} = \lambda^T \mathbf{M}_{nm}^{-1/2} \mathbf{D}_i^T \mathbf{V_i}^{-1} (\mathbf{y}_i - \mu_i)$, for any given $p\times1$ vector $\lambda$, $\Vert{\lambda}\Vert=1$. By the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality,
> $$Z_{nm,i}^2 \leq \lambda_\text{max}(\mathbf{M}_{nm}^{-1}\mathbf{H}_{nm})\lambda^T \mathbf{H}_{nm}^{-1/2}\mathbf{D}_i^T \mathbf{V_i}^{-1}\mathbf{D}_i \mathbf{H}_{nm}^{-1/2} \lambda (\mathbf{y}_i-\mu_i)^T\mathbf{V}_i^{-1}(\mathbf{y}_i-\mu_i)$$

Let $a= (\lambda^T M_{nm}^{-1/2}D_i^TV_i^{-1/2})^T$ and $b=V_i^{-1/2}(\mathbf{y}_i-\mathbf{\mu}_i)$. By Cauchy-Schwarz inequality, I have
$$\begin{split}
Z_{nm,i}^2 & \leq a^Ta b^Tb \\
& = \lambda^T M_{nm}^{-1/2}D_i^TV_i^{-1}D_i^TM_{nm}^{-1/2}\lambda (\mathbf{y}_i-\mathbf{\mu}_i)^TV_i^{-1}(\mathbf{y}_i-\mathbf{\mu}_i)\\
& = \lambda^T M_{nm}^{-1/2}H_{nm}^{1/2}H_{nm}^{-1/2}D_i^TV_i^{-1}D_i^TH_{nm}^{-1/2}H_{nm}^{1/2}M_{nm}^{-1/2}\lambda (\mathbf{y}_i-\mathbf{\mu}_i)^TV_i^{-1}(\mathbf{y}_i-\mathbf{\mu}_i)\\
\end{split}$$
And I'm lost since here ... Can anyone help complete the proof? Many thanks!

Comment: Hi Olivia. Welcome to CV. Please explain all the notations and terminologies. Also there are blind and visually impaired users of this site who interact with it using screen readers. The screen readers can't handle the equation in your screenshot.